# Integrating factor (exact equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(3x + (6/y)) + (x^2/y+ 3y/x)dy/dx=0$$

$$M_y=-6/y^2 $$

$$N_x= 2x/y - 3y/x^2$$

how do I go about finding the integrating factor for this equation? thanks for tips/solutions

Answer (score 1):

The integrating factor is $\quad \mu(x,y)=xy\quad$ There is little chance to find it  by intuition. So, the method to find it is shown below :

[image]